# Replace text in CSV from hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, hashtable

I'm trying to `Import-Csv "Newusers.csv"` that is an export from a payroll system. I need to import this to Active Directory and need to update the `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` column in the CSV file for each user.

Currently the export from the payroll system users a code for the sitename. I need to replace this code with the site name. I have a hashtable that has the site code = site name. I have over 100 site locations.

```
$hashtable = @{
    28 = 'Example Site 1'
    29 = 'Example Site 2'
    36 = 'Example Site 3'
    37 = 'Example Site 4'
    50 = 'Example Site 5'
    51 = 'Example Site 6'
    52 = 'Example Site 7'
    53 = 'Example Site 8'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have over 100 site locations

In that case you're definitely on the right path.

Use the site code value as the key when accessing the hashtable:

```
Import-Csv newusers.csv |ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.username -replace @{physicalDeliveryOffice=$hashtable[$_.sitecode]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If i need to just update the csv file (as this will be used for another system too) whats the command i need to use inplace of the set-aduser to just update the csv

Comment: Use the `-Append` parameter : `Export-Csv -Append -Path "C:\xxxxx\File.csv"`

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question, my bad

Answer (score 1):

To replace the site codes with site names in your CSV import the CSV, modify the column, then export the data back to a CSV. There are several ways you can approach this, e.g. by replacing the entire column using `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\newusers.csv'
(Import-Csv $file) |
    Select-Object *,@{n='SiteName';e={$hashtable[$_.sitecode]}} -Exclude sitecode |
    Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

or by simply changing the values in the column in a loop:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\newusers.csv'
$csv  = Import-Csv $file
foreach ($record in $csv) {
    $record.sitecode = $hashtable[$_.sitecode]
}
$csv | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```